# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freezes after "bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on"

Tags: 14.04, boot, bbswitch

So I've got a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS start up recently. It has been freezing on purple screen. I've changed `"quiet splash"` to `""` in `/etc/default/grub` to see what happens, and the last thing written before freezing is

```
[ 16.115628] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: bbswitch is bumblebee so I'd say you have a video driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently reinstalling video drivers fixed the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)